# Python to extract specific numbers from text file

Tags: python

I have a text file and inside the text file are binary numbers such as 35F,1,0,1,0,0. I want Python to find a specific combination but first there is a degrees number in front.

What I want Python to do is skip that degree F number in this example 35F and just search for all binary combination of 1,0,1,0,0. so the output should look something like this

```
28F 1,0,1,0,0
15F 1,0,1,0,0
18F 1,0,1,0,0
20F 1,0,1,0,0
22F 1,0,1,0,0
```

at this moment I have this code. The only problem with it I can't search for my own specific combination it only tells me how many duplicates there are.

```
import collections


with open('pythonbigDATA.txt') as infile:
    counts = collections.Counter(l.strip() for l in infile)
for line, count in counts.most_common():
    print count
```

Comment: look for [Python CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: Is `F ` always that place you want to split? Try `'28F 1,0,1,0,0'.partition('F ')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways, this seems the easiest:

```
import csv

combination = '1,0,1,0,0'.split(',')

with open('pythonbigDATA.txt') as infile:
    for row in csv.reader(infile):
        if row[1:] == combination:
            print row[0], ','.join(row[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

If all lines look like this `00F 0,0,0,0,0` you can use str.split() and keep the part after the first space.

```
counts = collections.Counter(l.split()[1] for l in infile)
```

Edit: You can also use split() if there's no space, and the input looks like this:  `00F,0,0,0,0,0`

```
counts = collections.Counter(l.split(',',1)[1] for l in infile)
```

Comment: In the input there are commas after the temperature, example: `35F,1,0,1,0,0`