# Python CSV specific line to extract

Tags: python, csv

I have two CSV files and I want python to open `file1.csv` and read line 7 from that file and look for that same binary code on the WHOLE `file2.csv`.

This is what I have so far but it does not work:

```
import csv

a = open('file1.csv','r').readline[7]


with open('file2.csv') as infile:
    for row in csv.reader(infile):
        if row[1:] == a: # This part is fine because i want to skip the first row 
            print row[0], ','.join(row[1:])
```

Comment: Do those two csv files have the same number of columns? Do they have the same delimiter? Can you give a small number of lines (e.g. 3) of each file? And you write that you want to "skip the first row", but in reality, you are skipping the first column and comparing a list to a string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to read up on how the [python csv library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) works :) You might also want to read up on how [list slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) works. I'll try to help you based on what I understood about your problem.

I have the same question that [@oliver-w](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2476444/oliver-w) had but I'll just assume your 'csv' files have only one column.

```
import csv

with open('file1.csv', 'r') as file1:
    # this is the value you will be searching for in file2.csv
    # you might need to change this to [6] if there is no header row in file1.csv
    val = list(csv.reader(file1))[7]

with open('file2.csv', 'r') as file2:
    reader = csv.reader(file2)
    reader.next() # this skips the first row of the file
    # this iteration will start from the second row of file2.csv
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == val:
            # your question doesn't clarify what your actual purpose is
            # so i don't know what should be here
```

Comment: Vape this is perfect. Thank you ... to clarify what I needed to be done [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379836/python-to-extract-specific-numbers-from-text-file/28380258#28380258] pretty much what I did is changed the combination = '1,0,1,0,0'.split(',') - see link to a csv file...... For example line 7 was the weather for new york, line 2 was for florida etc in file1. and file2 was an archive for each state going back to 1980.